# Pagination not working in custom grid collection

Tags: magento2, admin, collection, grid

I have created the grid with custom collection filter grid displayed proper but pagination not working. Any have an idea about the same. Please find below my code

```
 <?php

namespace Abc\Xyz\Block\Adminhtml\Customproduct;

use Magento\Framework\DataObject;

class Grid extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Extended {

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Module\Manager
     */
    protected $moduleManager;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Eav\Model\ResourceModel\Entity\Attribute\Set\CollectionFactory]
     */
    protected $_setsFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory
     */
    protected $_productFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Type
     */
    protected $_type;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status
     */
    protected $_status;
    protected $_collectionFactory;
    protected $_customcollection;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility
     */
    protected $_visibility;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Store\Model\WebsiteFactory
     */
    protected $_websiteFactory;
    protected $objectmanager;
    protected $_product;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Backend\Helper\Data $backendHelper
     * @param \Magento\Store\Model\WebsiteFactory $websiteFactory
     * @param \Magento\Eav\Model\ResourceModel\Entity\Attribute\Set\CollectionFactory $setsFactory
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $productFactory
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Type $type
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status $status
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility $visibility
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Module\Manager $moduleManager
     * @param array $data
     *
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveParameterList)
     */
    public function __construct(
    DataObject $dataObj, \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context, \Magento\Backend\Helper\Data $backendHelper, \Magento\Store\Model\WebsiteFactory $websiteFactory, \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection $collectionFactory, \Magento\Framework\Module\Manager $moduleManager, \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectmanager, \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product, \Abc\Supplierorder\Model\ResourceModel\Customproduct\Collection $customcollection, array $data = []
    ) {

        $this->_objectManager = $objectmanager;
        $this->_collectionFactory = $collectionFactory;
        $this->_customcollection = $customcollection;
        $this->_websiteFactory = $websiteFactory;
        $this->moduleManager = $moduleManager;
        $this->_product = $product;
        $this->_dataObj = $dataObj;
        parent::__construct($context, $backendHelper, $data);
    }

    /**
     * @return void
     */
    protected function _construct() {        
        parent::_construct();
        $this->setId('customproductGrid');
        $this->setDefaultSort('id');
        $this->setDefaultDir('DESC');
        $this->setSaveParametersInSession(true);
        $this->setPageSize(10);  
        $this->setUseAjax(true);             
        /*parent::_construct();
        $this->setId('customproductGrid');
        $this->setDefaultSort('id');
        $this->setDefaultDir('DESC');
        $this->setSaveParametersInSession(true);
        $this->setPageSize(10);        
        $this->setUseAjax(true);*/
    }

    protected function _prepareCollection() {
        try {            
            $customcol = array();
            $productcollection = $this->_customcollection;
            $collection = $this->_collectionFactory->addAttributeToSelect(array('entity_id','name','supplier'))->setPageSize(20);

            foreach ($collection as $col) {                                 
                $all_options = $col->getProductOptionsCollection();                  
                //$prod = $this->_product->load($col->getEntityId());
                //$all_options = $prod->getOptions();
                foreach ($all_options as $option) {
                    if ($option->getTitle() == 'Size') {
                        if ($option->getValues() != null) {
                            foreach ($option->getValues() as $value) {                                
                                $customcol = array();
                                $this->_dataObj = $this->_objectManager->create('Magento\Framework\DataObject');
                                $customcol['product_id'] = $col->getEntityId();
                                $customcol['name'] = $col->getName();
                                $customcol['sku'] = $value->getSku();
                                $customcol['supplier'] = $col->getSupplier();
                                $customcol['catalog_number'] = $value->getDescription();
                                $customcol['size'] = $value->getTitle();
                                $customcol['price'] = $value->getPrice();
                                $customcol['product_option_id'] = $col->getEntityId() . '_' . $value->getOptionTypeId();

                                $productcollection->addItem(
                                        $this->_dataObj->addData($customcol)
                                );
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            //print_r($productcollection->getData());exit;
//            $productcollection->setPageSize(10);
//            $productcollection->setCurPage(2);            
            $this->setCollection($productcollection);
            return parent::_prepareCollection();
            //return $this;
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
            die;
        }
    }

    protected function _prepareColumns() {
        $this->addColumn(
                'product_id', [
            'header' => __('ID'),
            'index' => 'product_id',
            'class' => 'product_id'
                ]
        );
        $this->addColumn(
                'name', [
            'header' => __('Product Name'),
            'index' => 'name',
            'class' => 'name'
                ]
        );
        $this->addColumn(
                'sku', [
            'header' => __('SKU'),
            'index' => 'sku',
            'class' => 'sku'
                ]
        );
        $this->addColumn(
                'supplier', [
            'header' => __('Supplier'),
            'index' => 'supplier',
            'class' => 'supplier'
                ]
        );
        $this->addColumn(
                'size', [
            'header' => __('Size'),
            'index' => 'size',
            'class' => 'size'
                ]
        );
        $this->addColumn(
                'catalog_number', [
            'header' => __('Catalog Number'),
            'index' => 'catalog_number',
            'class' => 'catalog_number'
                ]
        );
        $this->addColumn(
                'price', [
            'header' => __('Price'),
            'index' => 'price',
            'class' => 'price'
                ]
        );

        $this->addColumn(
                'in_products', [
            'header' => __('Select'),
            'type' => 'checkbox',
            'name' => 'in_products',
            'index' => 'product_option_id',
            'sortable' => false,
            'header_css_class' => 'col-select',
            'column_css_class' => 'col-select'
                ]
        );
        return parent::_prepareColumns();
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    protected function _getSelectedProducts() {
        $products = $this->getRequest()->getPost('products', []);
        return $products;
    }

    /**
     * @return \Magento\Store\Api\Data\StoreInterface
     */
    protected function _getStore() {
        $storeId = (int) $this->getRequest()->getParam('store', 0);
        return $this->_storeManager->getStore($storeId);
    }

    /**
     * @return $this
     */
    protected function _afterLoadCollection() {
        //$this->getCollection()->addOptionsToResult();
        return parent::_afterLoadCollection();
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getGridUrl() {
        return $this->getUrl('supplierorder/customproduct/index', array('_current' => true));
    }

}
```